# Add open terminal to panel

Tags: command-line, panel

Is there any way to pin a terminal to the panel?

I'm monitoring a server via `top` and would like to have some of the information (at least the first row e.g. the load average) always on my active workspace.

I could reduce the terminal size and have it **always on top** and **always on visible workspace** but this still takes to much space.

What I would like is a possibilty to add some of the `top` information to a notifier in the top panel.
Is there any setting in terminal I could use, or are there any other possibilities?
I don't need to use terminal if there is any other application that can be used to show this information.

Comment: You could try the applets. There are some applets that show the utilization, and CPU usage. I also use AWN, that has a CPU monitor. http://imgur.com/afneR

Answer (score 1):

You could try [guake](http://packages.ubuntu.com/guake)[image: Install guake] - this is a drop-down terminal, which can be configured to be visible in a small line under the top panel.

Comment: It's even worse, as it does not allow me to have multiple terminal windows side by side. I would have to switch tabs.